# When should I use plural form of the noun after the numeral?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, numbers, reading-aloud

Which is correct: "one hundred and one apple" or "one hundred and one apples"?

The first version seems more likely, but there are "101 Dalmatian*s*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a sentence where the apples are the subject.

*One hundred and one apple rolls down the street.*  That sounds pretty strange. A disagreement with the verb would be even worse.

It's more than one apple, so it should be plural.

Comment: It sounds exactly like that in Russian, so that was a bad example :)

Answer (score 2):

Plural form ->  greater than one.

Hence, 'one hundred and one APPLE**S**' is CORRECT. (101 > 1)

Comment: 1.01 is certainly plural.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph, Basically, 1.01 is still > 1. I just provided the case as other users might ask. I believe they should ask it in a different question so as to make it searchable online. (take note: I said, I'm NOT here to answer the case where 1.01 > 1)

Comment: I'm trying to think of what form I would use after something like 1.01, and I think it's plural.  *One point zero one unit has been shipped*?  No, that sounds wrong.  *One point zero one units have been shipped* sounds much more natural.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to handle this is to simply use numerals, particularly for three-digit numbers:

> *101 apples*.

That said, if you must spell out the number for some reason, the noun should agree with the entire value, not just the last digit:

> *one hundred and one apples*.

You may find some style guides that recommend omitting the [*and*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Number.html):

> *one hundred one apples*.